# nfs server setting permission for different groups

Tags: nfs

I have two groups "masters" and "slaves" i'm setting up an NFS server for the partition "subject"

and I want the "masters" group to be able to read & write to the "subject" while the "slaves" group are only allowed to read. Users who are in neither group should not be able to read or write from the partition

I was thinking about using the export option rw=list but i'm uncertain how the syntax would look

would i put something like this?

```
  /subject 192.168.0.0/24(rw=master1,master2,master3,sync)
```

then i can put the masters and slaves in a group and then make that group the only onces able to access /subject.

nfs version 4

Comment: Are you using NFS version 3 or 4?

Comment: nfs version 4 i've edited the main post now

Answer (score 0):

The **rw** or **ro** export options control client host wide behavior. If you want to control based on user groups, then you have to use directory permissions or apply NFsv4 ACLs.